# It serves as a bed vs. serves as bed

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

My google searches remain somewhat inconclusive, is it:

> The cardboard serves as bed.

Or:

> The cardboard serves as a bed.

Ngram of "served as bed,served as a bed" shows the version with the article leading 5 to 1, but which one is correct, is it regional?

Answer (score 2):

An article is not necessary with **as**, but it is certainly acceptable.

In the version without article, the noun is a "role" noun.  The cardboard is not an actual bed but serves the role of a bed; it fulfills some of the functions of a bed.

> A sheet of cardboard serves as bed, and a wad of newspapers as pillow.

Comment: Do you know of another example where the noun serves as role noun and doesnt require an article. Is "in question" a type of it?

Comment: Or maybe "I do not have the hammer **in hand** "? I've just heard it said, sorry for a double comment,

Comment: @Jakub: There are many situations in which an article is not used.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with Ngram, as it gives you exactly what you ask for, but not necessarily what you want.  In this case, if you actually check the references listed for "serve as bed" you'll see the following phrases:

> ... serve as bed *coverings*
>
> ... serve as bed *pads*
>
> ... serve as bed *lamps*

These are plural compound nouns (bed table, bed linens, etc.) and the grammar is standard.

There are a few references that use the phrase as in your question:

> A portion of the floor inside the room is strewn with green Kans or Kusa (grass) to **serve as bed** for the prospective mother ...

But this is not, I think, typical and may be a regional or old-fashioned dialect.  I personally have never seen or used "serve as *bed*", at least not in the same way as "serve as *home*" or "serve as *food*".